# How to update data in a diverging stacked bar-chart d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QbFZrEGWnzARc2xiROtL?p=preview) that updates data from one csv file to another, the yaxis updates accordingly but the rectangles don't.

The `.attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(y(d[0])) - y(d[1]); });` portion of the code still has the old data from the previous file (I'm guessing).

I'm guessing this is because I haven't declared `.data(series)` in the `updateData()` function, I remember doing something like this in another chart

```
g.selectAll(".bar").data(series).transition()
```

etc...
but this doesn't work in this chart.

I can't figure it out, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you didn't join the new data to existing bars.

To make this work well, you will want to specify a key for category of data when you join the series to the g elements to ensure consistency (although I notice that category-1 is positive in the first dataset, and negative in the second, but this is test data i guess)

Here's the updated plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/EoEvVWiTji7y5V3SQTKJ?p=info), with the relevant code highlighted below:

```
g.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(series, function(d){ return d.key  }) //add function to assign a key
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "bars")  //so its easy to select later on
 //etc
...



function updateData() {

    d3.csv("data2.csv", type, function(error, data) {

        ///etc      

        let bars = d3.selectAll(".bars")  //select the g elements

        bars.data(series, function(d){ return d.key  }) //join the new data
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
        .transition()   
      .duration(750)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(y(d[0])) - y(d[1]); });
```